# .htaccess seems to continue after Last flag

Tags: .htaccess

In the small portfolio website I am making I want to have clean urls. For this I use a .htaccess file. At the moment my website runs at 127.0.0.1/website. My .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /website

RewriteRule ^about$ index.php?page=0 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^portfolio$ index.php?page=1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^cv$ index.php?page=2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^contact$ index.php?page=3 [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^.*$ about [L,R]
```

If I remove the last line, everything works fine. I can go to `127.0.0.1/website/about`, and the server shows me `127.0.0.1/website/index.php?page=0`, while the url does not change. However, I want every other url to be redirected to `127.0.0.1/website/about`, and I tried to do that with the last line. However, if I now try to go to `127.0.0.1/website/anything`, where anything is any string, it redirects me to `127.0.0.1/website/about?page=0`. In addition to this, I would expect `127.0.0.1/website/about` to be handles fine, because of the Last flag at the first rewrite rule, but this redirects me to the same bad url.

I am clueless of why this does not work, and confused, because to me it seems like it is skipping the Last flag. I hope someone can point out what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To explain further what is happening, the problem is that each time an input url is actually matched and rewritten by any rule, then the engine starts a new round with the rewritten version, to possibly rewrite again the rewritten url. The `[L]` flag only lets you break the current round. I agree this scheme can be misleading, if you are not careful enough you can easily get a 500 internal server error due to an infinite loop.

Comment: Thank you very much for the confirmation. I figured this was the case because of the fact that Deadooshkas answer worked. I now know how to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

last rule rewrites everything so pattern must be more specific

```
RewriteRule !^index\.php$ about [L,R]
```

Comment: This indeed fixes the problem. It also helped me understand what the problem is, even though you did not explain thoroughly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /website

RewriteRule ^about$ index.php?page=0 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^portfolio$ index.php?page=1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^cv$ index.php?page=2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^contact$ index.php?page=3 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/cv        [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/about     [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/contact    [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/portfolio  [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /about [R,L]
```

It will redirect everything that isn't `/cv`, `/about`, `/contact` or `/portfolio` to `/about`.

Comment: Thanks for the try, but this does not work. It gives the same output as before. I think the problem is that my first 4 rules change the url in index.php?page=num, so the rewrite conditions are not valid anymore. The fact that Deadooshkas works confirms this. Thanks anyway.